# What does "Running application "App" with appParams" mean in React Native?

Tags: react-native, sentry

We're trying to investigate a React Native crash in production. We're using Sentry to monitor error logs. We've found that just before a crash this message appears:

> Running application "App" with appParams: {"rootTag":11}. **DEV** === false, development-level warning are OFF, performance optimizations are ON

For instance: 
[image: instance]

Does this mean in React Native the the app was restarted or came back from background?

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to test this locally by studying the logging behaviour in a normal debug build. I have noticed the `Running application` logs only when an application is started, *not* when the application is brought from the background to the foreground.

The logging originates from [React Native's AppRegistry.js](https://github.com/facebook/react-native/blob/e10f7788c4ebf29d96594f9753264bdf6146f0cf/Libraries/ReactNative/AppRegistry.js#L172).